# Dependency, recycler-animator library is giving Run time error

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-recyclerview

**compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.1'**

I just put this library in dependency after when I run my application it is throwing exception due to this my app crashed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm just put this library to my gradle Dependencies and when I remove this library my application working normally.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.10.8'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'

    //  (sammy)
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.1'
      //
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}}
```

**LOG ERROR**

```
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{earn.free.cashback.snapcash/earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivi    ty}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error   inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)   
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateI mplV7.java:256)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:1 09) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:80)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:92)
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
03-20 08:33:55.355 1565-1565/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```